# Exoplayer in viewpager2 still play old video

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I creat exoplayer in viewpager2 to play video like YouTube shorts and tiktok put
when scroll up or down the old video and still play i need to stop the
old video play and only the new video its play

> My MainActivity.java

```
   package com.example.vdodemo;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    
    
    import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        ViewPager2 viewPager2;
        videoadapter adapter;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    
            viewPager2 = (ViewPager2) findViewById(R.id.vpager);
    
            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<videomodel> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<videomodel>()
                    .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("videos"), videomodel.class).build();
    
            adapter = new videoadapter(options);
            viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);
            
            
        }
        
        
    
        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            adapter.startListening();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            adapter.stopListening();
        }
    
    }
```

> this my videoadapter.java

package com.example.vdodemo;

import ...

public class videoadapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<videomodel, videoadapter.myviewholder> {

```
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> pathsList;
private AppCompatActivity activity;

private Timer _timer = new Timer();
private double positionc;
private TimerTask check;
private ProgressBar progressbar11;
private ViewPager2 viewPager;


public videoadapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<videomodel> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull videomodel model) {
    holder.setdata(model);
    
    
}

@NonNull
@Override
public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_video_row, parent, false);
    return new myviewholder(view);
}

class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    PlayerView playerView;
    SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;
    LinearLayout sec_mid;
    ProgressBar progressbar1;
    
    public myviewholder(@NonNull View view) {
        super(view);
        
        playerView = (PlayerView) view.findViewById(R.id.statusSliderVideo);
        sec_mid = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sec_controlvid1);
        progressbar1 = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressbar11);
    }
    
    void setdata(videomodel obj) {
        
        progressbar1.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        
        // get data
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(obj.getUrl());
        simpleExoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(playerView.getContext()).setSeekBackIncrementMs(1000)
        .setSeekForwardIncrementMs(1000).build();
        
        playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
        playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        
        
        MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUri);
        simpleExoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare();
        
        simpleExoPlayer.addListener(new Player.Listener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                
                
                
                if (playbackState == Player.STATE_READY) {
                    
                    
                    
                    simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                
                    
                    } else if (playbackState == Player.STATE_ENDED) {
                    
                    
                    simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        });
        
        
        Activity activity = new Activity();
        
        check = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        
                        progressbar1.setMax((int) simpleExoPlayer.getDuration());
                        progressbar1.setProgress((int) simpleExoPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                        
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        _timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(check, (int) (0), (int) (1));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

When playing videos in recyclerview, you need to have a global instance of `SimpleExoPlayer`. It must not be a part of your viewholder. Keep it globally in your activity and then observe changes in your recyclerview. On scroll, check if that view holder/item is still visible or not. If item is not visible, stop the current video by calling `exoplayer.stop()` and play a new video on same exoplayer instance.